# How to set Target Sdk on Feature Module (Gradle 7.0.2)

Tags: android, gradle, dynamic-feature-module

I want to change what was previously a `library` (`com.android.library`) to a `feature module` (`com.android.dynamic-feature`). However, when I do so, I am unable to set the `targetSdk` or `targetSdkVersion`:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.dynamic-feature")
    kotlin("kapt")
    kotlin("android")
}

android { // this = DynamicFeatureExtension
    compileSdk = BuildConfig.SdkVersion.COMPILE

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = BuildConfig.SdkVersion.MIN
        targetSdk = BuildConfig.SdkVersion.TARGET // targetSdk is not found
        targetSdkVersion(BuildConfig.SdkVersion.TARGET) // targetSdkVersion is not found
    ...
}
```

The gradle version is 7.0.2:
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip`

I notice that when I compare it with the [Plaid App](https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid/blob/main/dribbble/build.gradle), which doesn't suffer the same problems, that their gradle version is 5.6.4.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Got anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
defaultConfig.apply {
        minSdk = BuildConfig.SdkVersion.MIN
        targetSdk = BuildConfig.SdkVersion.TARGET
        targetSdkVersion(BuildConfig.SdkVersion.TARGET)
}
```